APIM - Validating a thumbprint against certificates uploaded to API Management
I currently have the below policy which validates the certificate thumbprint against "any" certificate uploaded to API Management:
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint))">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate"/>
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>

But I want to validate a thumbprint against a "specific" certificate uploaded to API Management, not "any".
I have tried the below policy:
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || context.Deployment.Certificates["MyCert"].Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint)">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate"/>
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>

"MyCert" is the "Id" of the "Client Certificate" in API which refers to the certificate uploaded in Key Vault.

But when I call the API, it throws this error: Expression evaluation failed. The given key 'MyCert' was not present in the dictionary. at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
Can someone please help me with this issue?

Use the correct Thumbprint of your certificate

Sorry, can you explain a little bit more? What do you mean by "correct Thumbprint"?
I'm trying to validate the "incoming request certificate's thumbprint" against the "specific uploaded certificate" in APIM.

context.Deployment.Certificates.Values doesn't contain Certificate Id parameter to filter.  You can validate it by using <set-variable name="Values" value="@((string)string.Join(", ", context.Deployment.Certificates.Values))" /> expression.
You can use the below given policy to pass the Thumbprint of a specific certificate uploaded in APIM to verify against the incoming certificate.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate != null || (string)context.Deployment.Certificates.Values.FirstOrDefault(cert => cert.Thumbprint == "<APIMCertThumbprint>")?.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                    <set-body>Valid certificate</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
                    <set-body>Invalid or missing client certificate</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policies>

Due to some limitations I can't pass the certificate information in request body, so I am testing by storing the value of thumbprint in set-variable against the uploaded certificate in APIM.




I think you're right. I've been researching the whole day today on how to validate the certificate against a specific certificate uploaded in APIM by searching its Id or something but there's no way.
I think validating against "Any()" is the only option.

Yes, you can pass the thumbprint like the way I am providing in my policy

@NaveenSharma Done!
